# How to remove all created labels on my form

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have this code and I want to know how to remove all created labels in my form.

I tried to put lbl.dispose() and ltr.dispose() on a Button but it says that it's not declared or inaccessible.

```
Dim break As Integer = 99


            For i = 0 To break

            If jobA > 0 And jobA > time Then
                jobA = jobA - time
                Dim lbl As Label = New Label
                Dim ltr As Label = New Label
                lbl.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(x, 280)
                lbl.Size = New System.Drawing.Point(20, 20)
                lbl.Text = time + spudow(waifuu)
                ltr.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(y, 250)
                ltr.Size = New System.Drawing.Point(20, 20)
                ltr.Text = "A"
                Me.Controls.Add(lbl)
                Me.Controls.Add(ltr)

            ElseIf jobA > 0 And jobA < time Then
                Dim lbl As Label = New Label
                Dim ltr As Label = New Label
                lbl.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(x, 280)
                lbl.Size = New System.Drawing.Point(20, 20)
                lbl.Text = jobA + spudow(waifuu)
                ltr.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(y, 250)
                ltr.Size = New System.Drawing.Point(20, 20)
                ltr.Text = "A"
                Me.Controls.Add(lbl)
                Me.Controls.Add(ltr)

            ElseIf jobA = time Then
                Dim lbl As Label = New Label
                Dim ltr As Label = New Label
                lbl.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(x, 280)
                lbl.Size = New System.Drawing.Point(20, 20)
                lbl.Text = jobA + spudow(waifuu)
                ltr.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(y, 250)
                ltr.Size = New System.Drawing.Point(20, 20)
                ltr.Text = "A"
                Me.Controls.Add(lbl)
                Me.Controls.Add(ltr)

            End If

  Me.Refresh()
```

Comment: This code does not try and remove anything. You could create a `ListOf(Label)` and add the label to it every time you create one. Then you can use that list to remove the labels you created...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like Zaggler's idea of using a List(Of Label), but I'll post another approach using the .Tag property of the Labels instead.  This will work well enough if all the Labels will only be added to the Form itself.  If you're going to spread the Labels across multiple containers then use the List(Of Label) approach instead as it will be easier.  Additionally, you can get rid of a lot of redundant code by restructuring like this (I assume there is more un-shown code that is somehow changing the "x" and "y" values!):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim break As Integer = 99
    For i = 0 To break

        Dim lbl As Label = New Label
        Dim ltr As Label = New Label
        lbl.Tag = "dynamic"
        ltr.Tag = "dynamic"
        lbl.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(x, 280)
        lbl.Size = New System.Drawing.Point(20, 20)
        lbl.Text = ""
        ltr.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(y, 250)
        ltr.Size = New System.Drawing.Point(20, 20)
        ltr.Text = "A"

        If jobA > 0 Then
            If jobA > time Then
                jobA = jobA - time
                lbl.Text = time + spudow(waifuu)
            ElseIf jobA < TimeOfDay Then
                lbl.Text = jobA + spudow(waifuu)
            End If
        ElseIf jobA = time Then
            lbl.Text = jobA + spudow(waifuu)
        End If

        If lbl.Text <> "" Then
            Me.Controls.Add(lbl)
            Me.Controls.Add(ltr)
        End If

    Next i
End Sub
```

Then, when you want to remove the dynamic Labels, you can use code like this:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim labels = Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label).Where(Function(x) x.Tag = "dynamic").ToList
    For Each lbl As Label In labels
        lbl.Dispose()
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Sub RemoveAllLabels()
    Dim Labels As New List(Of Label)
    Dim Stack As New Stack(Of Control)
    Stack.Push(Me)
    While Stack.Count > 0
      Dim Ctrl As Control = Stack.Pop()
      Labels.Add(TryCast(Ctrl, Label))
      For Each C As Control In Ctrl.Controls
        Stack.Push(C)
      Next
    End While
    For Each L As Label In Labels
      If Not IsNothing(L) Then L.Dispose()
    Next
End Sub
```